# How do I make the window roll across the rows instead of the columns in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, window, rolling-computation

I have the following code that rolls a window of size 3 column-wise (i.e. downwards as depicted in green in the image). However, I'd like the window to roll row-wise (i.e. rightwards as depicted in blue in the image).
[image]

```
window_size = 3 

numbers_series = X  #X is my dataframe
windows = numbers_series.rolling(window_size)
moving_averages = windows.mean()
moving_averages_list = moving_averages.values.tolist()
without_nans = moving_averages[window_size - 1:]
print(without_nans)
```

The output column-wise is:
[image]

But this is not what I want - I'd like it to give me the mean of the windows row-wise. How do I go about achieving this?

EDIT:
After editing the above code to include axis=1 in the rolling function, this is the output I get:
[image]

I'm not sure how the values of 520.67, 635.33, etc are computed above. I was expecting the following (first cell: 788 + 43 + 345)/3 = 392, etc...):

[image]

Comment: Re to your edit: even though you switched to `axis=1`, this line `without_nans = moving_averages[window_size - 1:]` is still dropping row-wise. You now need to drop column wise: `without_nans = moving_averages[:, window_size - 1:]` (note the `:`s).

Comment: ...also if you were to calculate the third row in your last image, you'd see where 520.67, 635.33, etc are coming from...

Comment: As mentioned in the below comments, you can pass `min_periods=1` so that it computes means even when there is a lack of data with respect to window size.

Comment: Got it, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pandas.DataFrame.rolling has a parameter for the axis.
[DataFrame.rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html)

```
DataFrame.rolling(
    window, 
    min_periods=None, 
    center=False, 
    win_type=None, 
    on=None, 
    axis=0, # Set axis to 1.
    closed=None)
```

Comment: Thank you - just tried this but it gives me NaN values in the first two columns and incorrect mean values for row-wise operation

Comment: The window starts at df.iloc[0,0]m but spans on the left up to df.iloc[0,-2]. So you can either offset the window to start on df.iloc[0,2] or you can drop the first two columns.

Comment: @Kareena Your column-wise code was also giving `NaN`s but for first two rows. You can pass `min_periods=1` to force it compute means even when there are less than 3 observations i.e., first two columns. Also, how did you conclude that the mean values were incorrect? What were you expecting, what did you get?

Comment: yes, the first two columns being NaN is expected. It depends on what you want. I do not know what you want but I may help if you show me your expected output. ;)

Comment: Thank you Florian Fasmeyer and @MustafaAydın - I edited my question above to show the output - I'm not sure how those values are computed. I have also included a snippet of what I was initially looking for in terms of the mean values at each cell with the rolling window of size 3.